# set number of threads in R package that uses Fortran and PpenMP

Tags: r, fortran, openmp

I'm writing a simple R package that uses Fortran and OpenMP. This is my fortran module:

```
module im_f_module
   use omp_lib
   implicit none
   contains

subroutine fill_matrix(N,K,A,ncores) bind(C, name="fill_")
   use, intrinsic                                         :: iso_c_binding, only : c_double, c_int
   integer(c_int), intent(in)                             :: N,K, ncores
   real(c_double), DIMENSION(N, K), intent(out)           :: A
   integer                                                :: nn, kk, thread_num
   ! Specify number of threads to use:
    !$ call omp_set_num_threads(ncores)
    !$omp parallel private(thread_num)
    !$omp parallel do
    do nn=1,N
       do kk=1,K
          !$ thread_num = omp_get_thread_num()
          A(nn,kk) = thread_num
       end do
       !print *, A(nn, :)
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do
end subroutine fill_matrix



end module im_f_module
```

When I call the R fucntion that calls the module I want each ellement of the matrix to have a thread number. For example:

```r
fill_my_matrix(N = 2, K = 2, ncores = 4)
```

Should have 4 different values. Alas, it only has one:

```r
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
```

My guess is that `!$ call omp_set_num_threads(ncores)` is not setting the number of threads to 4. **How can I fix this?**

In case this is helpful, all the code for my package is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/ignacio82/fill_my_matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using the `OpenMPController` package. If there is a better way of doing this, I would love to learn it. For now, I just modified my R function like follows:

```r
#'@export
#'@useDynLib fortranMatrix, .registration = TRUE
fill_my_matrix <- function(N=10, K=5, nthreads=4) {
  (OpenMPController::omp_set_num_threads(nthreads))
  A <- .Fortran("fill",
                N = as.integer(N),
                K = as.integer(K),
                A = matrix(1982,nrow = N, ncol = K),
                nthreads = as.integer(nthreads))
  return(A$A)
}
```

And this is what I get when I call it:

```r
> fill_my_matrix(N = 6, K = 6, nthreads = 6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    2    2    2    2    2    2
[4,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
[5,]    4    4    4    4    4    4
[6,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
```